# Whats the use of Migration History in Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm getting the "The model backing the context has changed since the database was created" when I deploy to my code to the test environment.  The database was created by running the script output from `update-database -script` on the database.  So it originally had the Migration History table with the same values as my development database server.  There is quite a lot of discussion around this already - most of it suggesting simply dropping the table.  So I've dropped it and everything is fine.

But is it?  Is that really the idea?  Or am I likely not using the migrations right?  I've not posted any code because I'm not sure what would help you the most.

EDIT: I'll put this another way?  I generated the sql script from the console inside VS while pointing at my local SQL Express.  I've taken that exact script (including the migration history table and insert at the end) and run it on an entirely new database server (test).  I've released my website code to the matching test web server, and I get the error.  Is this the way migrations are supposed to be used?

Comment: I'm sure you've already tried something like this, but have you done a refresh or update on the EF items in your solution?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Im using code first.  I've added a bit to the question in case it's unclear what I'm talking about

Answer (score 2):

If you used the -script flag after Update-Database, that doesn't actually update the database. It only outputs the SQL script for your convenience. You have to run Update-Database without the -script flag in order to actually update the database.

In order of things, you should run:

- Enable-Migrations (just once for the lifetime of your project)
- Add-Migration (once for every time a dev adds model changes)
- Update-Database (once after you or anyone else adds a migration)

I wrote a blog post with step-by-step instructions, a working sample, and common issues.
http://wakeupandcode.com/entity-framework-code-first-migrations/

Hope this helps!